# bash script that downloads and processes file from a url given as an argument

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to be able to download and process a downloaded file with a single command from within a bash script. The filename should be saved with original filename.

I may be going about this all wrong, but how do I get new filename downloaded by wget as a variable?

For example: `process.sh "https://demo.io/files.php?action=download&id=123456"`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "no argument supplied"
else
    echo "$# arguments:"
    for x in "$@"; do
        wget --content-disposition "$x"
        mediainfo "$new_file"
    done
fi
```

I found a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/983813/get-filename-from-a-wget-content-disposition) that has one unaccepted answer that gets close as it produces the correct filename as an output. They suggest:

```
wget --content-disposition -nv "https://demo.io/files.php?action=download&id=123456" 2>&1 |cut -d\" -f2
```

However, when I try to put it into a variable like this, it fails.

```
...
new_file=$(wget --content-disposition -nv "$x" 2>&1 |cut -d\" -f2)
echo $new_file
mediainfo $new_file"
```

Comment: How about to "force" a filename with "-O filename.ext" ?

Comment: I want to keep the original filenames. I don't see any way to do it that way without downloading twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works and saves file correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "no argument supplied"
else
    echo "$# arguments:"
    for x in "$@"; do
        new_file=$(wget --content-disposition -nv "$x" 2>&1 |cut -d\" -f2)
        mediainfo "$new_file"
    done
fi
```